# Quickblox-WebRTC iOS: QBRTCVideoRenderer property has error for rendererView, unknown type view

Tags: quickblox

I have used Quickblox-WebRTC, but it fails to import in swift files

Here is my pod file looks like:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
use_frameworks!

target 'QuickBloxCall' do
pod 'QuickBlox', '~> 2.6.6'
pod 'Quickblox-WebRTC', '~> 2.2'
end
```

I have included the QuickbloxWebRTC and Quickblox in my Bridging header.

[image: Bridging header image]

And I am getting below error while compiling:

[image: error while running]

Can somebody point out what I did wrong?

Comment: Found it. Very silly mistake of mine. Just add #import<UIKit/UIKit.h> as first statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. Very silly mistake of mine. Just add #import <`UIKit/UIKit.h`> as first statement